# Help on basic reporting of negative binomial glm output

Tags: chi-squared-test, biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution

I have run some glm.nb models in R comparing count data between genotypes of animals.

I am new to R and have not run a nb before. It was suggested to me by a colleague and unfortunately now I'm lost.

I just, please, need some simple help and guidance on the correct values to report.
I understand I will be reporting the coefficients, SE and corresponding p values that are generated from:

```r
Call:
glm.nb(formula = PIRI ~ Treatment_2 + Genotype_2, data = Cfos, 
       init.theta = 4.608310936, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.8014  -0.6223  -0.1048   0.4419   1.4527  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        3.9416     0.1538  25.635   <2e-16 ***
Treatment_2vs WT   0.1169     0.2229   0.525   0.5998    
Genotype_2WT      -0.4906     0.2308  -2.125   0.0336 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(4.6083) family 
  taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 34.418  on 27  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 29.667  on 25  degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 259.61

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  4.61 
      Std. Err.:  1.36 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -251.612 
Likelihood ratio test
Model 1: PIRI ~ Treatment_2 + Genotype_2
Model 2: PIRI ~ 1
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   4 -125.81                     
2   2 -128.00 -2 4.3893     0.1114
```

However I'm confused as to why my Chi square is not significant when my variable genotype is.

Further, Treatment and Genotype have 2 levels. How can they both be compared to the 1 intercept?

Again I'm really sorry I know everyone here is more advanced and I need to gain a better understanding of these models, I just really need some guidance.